# Can't flip bits on byte or switch bits to all ones for some reason, not working

Tags: assembly, x86

Hey I'm kinda new to asm, and this problem is keeping me up all night
that i can't solve it, so i'm hoping to get some help. for some reason the expression

or al, 11111111

when al = AA is giving me EF, instead of FF. And when i try

xor al, 11111111

it gives me 6D instead of 55. I don't understand because i thought the or method would give me all ones and the xor would flip the bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

11111111 is a decimal number (eleven million, one hundred and eleven thousand, one hundred and eleven).

You need a different syntax to specify that that's a binary number; or, specify it as a hexadecimal number.

Comment: I probably should have mentioned it, but i've already tried that.
If i code "xor al, 0x11111111" it gives me BB, instead of 55.

Comment: @user1831680 The `0x` prefix specifies hexadecimal, not binary: so, try `0xFF`; or, to specify a binary number, maybe the correct syntax is `0b11111111`.